# Is it possible to scroll Tkinter Listboxes without a scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, raspberry-pi

I would like to create GUI on my RPi so that I can scroll through Listbox like I do in my iPhone, without the use of a scrollbar. In other words, by just touching the listbox and 'flicking' your finger up/down, I would like to be able to scroll.

Can this scrolling method be done with TKinter or any GUI for RPi?

Comment: I would recommend that you take a look at [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home). Tkinter is much more suited to basic, old-school desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

Just have a look how the binding of scrollbars work.

How can you achieve the desired effect? Bin Mouse-Move events (touch move is nothing else) and use it to connect it to yview / xview depending on what scroll you want to have.

(e.g. check the direction your mouse moves inside your callback and use that information to trigger the scrolling event.)

If further help is needed, let us know.

**Edit:**

Here some "dummy-code"...

```
# this is your callback bound to mouse-move event
def mouse_move_callback(event):
    # use event.y with a previous remembered y value to determine
    # directions
    directions = 1 # just as an example, could also be -1

    # scroll the listbox vertically. 
    # to increase scrolling speed, either multiply counter by some value >1
    # or replace 'units' which means scroll 1 character in the current setting 
    # by 'pages' for larger steps. 'pages' should scroll the visible 
    # area of the listbox further.
    listbox.yview_scroll(1, 'units')
```

You could also use mouse button press and mouse button release to trigger the actions. Mouse button press would then store an y value (beginn of scroll) and mouse button release would be bound to the above callback.

Comment: is there a possibility that you could kindly share a sample code?

Comment: If this fixed your problem please let other users know by accepting the answer.